# I have noise and need help

Tags: noise-reduction

Ok I'm so tired of the cycles noise problem on interior scene. Plese can you help me? I'm in a rush. This is my scene and a process of a 600 samples render (don't need to finish it for you to see how horrible it is). It`s incredible noisy.

This is my glass node (I'm sure is not the problem), my render configuration and my lighting. I`m using portals.The denoising asset only make things worst. Have an HDRI which is giving all the lighting (no sun, even noiser).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Martin Z, If you read my post and compare it with those you sent me, you will be note that I experimented with all the factors that they quote in all of those "noobies" posts. I mean, amount of samples, clamping, bounces, caustics, filter glossy, denoising asset, glass shader configuration and HDRI multiple importance. So yes, I am worried about this particular scene. That's because I'm posting it. Thank you.

Comment: Render a small region defining it with ctrl+b(ctrl+alt+b to remove) with something like 15 000 samples. You will see that the noise disapears eventually. This is normal rendering process.

Comment: Yep. I got a 15.000 samples clean render now. I need it huge so, that's not my christsmas.Thank you!

Comment: 15000 works because it's probably way too much. Look into how you should dertermine sample amount, also how clamping works. Area lights render way faster than HDRI. Glass objects could have all rays disabled except camera's for visible reflections. Poly count matters as well - no point to have objects that are not visible outside. Else than that... be prapared - rendering takes a long time. I render interiors and it is not uncommon to have render times in days for a single 4K image (if I used an average 4 core CPU which I don't, I use free SheepIt render farm and can really recommend it).

Comment: Thank you Martin. Yes I resolved it with 6.000 samples and it looks clean enough. Arround 12 hours. I will look for that render farm! I'm thinking in try Corona with Blender for interiors. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

1-Try to put more samples.
2-Clamp indirect light.
3-Use denoising.
4-Use bigger light sources.
5-Use architectual glass shader.
[image]

The architectual shader has reflections but not caustics.
[image]

Comment: Amazing shader I will try it! Thank you, this blog is amazing.

Comment: "The architectual shader has reflections but not caustics."

That's clever!